# Naming File Dynamically By Date

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have been trying to get my express app to dynamically name the files that phantom.js produces monthly. My intention is to also have a database that timestamps and holds the name of each file so that it can be retrieved easily later.

My question is how to dynamically name the files based on the date they are generated.

My phantom.js module is as follows:

```js
var page = require('webpage').create();

page.paperSize = {
  format:'Tabloid',
  orientation: 'landscape',
  margin: '1cm'
};
page.viewportSize = {
  width: 1980,
  height: 1080
};
page.open('<sitename>/', function() {
  page.render('./monthly.pdf');
  phantom.exit();
});
```

How do I dynamically name the monthly.pdf name on render. I have a cronjob that runs this script the first of every month. The idea is to be able to have a list of old monthly.pdf's that can be accessed through static files automatically based on the name and the database entry.

Any questions or clarification let me know.

Comment: Can't you just use `new Date()`?

Comment: I want it in the form monthly-07222015.pdf for example. I didn't know if new Date() could do that @remus

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this easily with [`Date()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date):

```
var d = new Date();
var filename = './monthly-' + d.getDate() + '/' + d.getMonth() + '/' + d.getFullYear() + '.pdf';
```

Or even simpler using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com):

```
var filename = moment().format('[./monthly-]MMDDYYYY[.pdf]');
```